# Question about inserting assembly code in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

I am working on VC++ compiler. I want to accomplish the following

The variables s.AddrFrame.Offset and s.AddrStack.Offset contain the value of EBP and ESP respectively. Offset is a 64 bit unsigned integer. My machine is little-endian.

```
typedef unsigned __int64 DWORD64;
```

I want to extract the value of old EBP and the return address. Assuming the address EBP + 1 contains the old 32 bit EBP value and EBP + 5 the return address I wrote the following code:

```
unsigned int old_ebp = 0;
unsigned int ret_addr = 0;

__asm{

mov old_ebp, DWORD PTR [s.AddrFrame.Offset + 1] 
mov ret_addr, DWORD PTR [s.AddrStack.Offset + 5]

}
```

But this is not compiling

```
xxxx.cpp(1130) : error C2415: improper operand type
```

Please Help

Comment: What is `s.AddrFrame.Offset`? Is that a reference to a nested C++ structure? Could you include the declaration for that?

Comment: @Greg: Sorry about that. I have added the info in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use two memory operands for `mov`; one must be a register. So, in your case, you need to have two `mov` instructions:

```
mov eax, [s.AddrFrame.Offset + 1]
mov old_ebp, eax
```

and analogously for `ret_addr`.

Comment: s.AddrFrame.Offset is a 64 bit integer. Will this not create any problems?

Comment: The assembler just sees an address - it doesn't care what the type backing it is.